# Conditional types not working as expected typescript

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have this ts code.

```
type NumberOrNever<T> = T extends number ? T : never

function f<T>(o: T) : NumberOrNever<T> {
    if (typeof o === "number") return o;
    throw "Not a number!"
}

const b = f(4);
const c = f({});
```

The playground gives red lines under the `return 0` with the message `Type 'T & number' is not assignable to type 'NumberOrNever<T>'`Why is this and how do I resolve this?

However, in the typescript playground, the playground correctly recognizes that b will be a number and c is never. Al tough it does not recognize that b will be 4. It just says number. Why is this? Because with something like this:

```
function f<T>(o: T) : T {
    if (typeof o === "number") return o;
    throw "Not a number!"
}
const b = f(4);
```

b will be types as 4.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this works.

```
function f<T>(o: T): NumberOrNever<T> {
  if (typeof o === "number") {
    return o as NumberOrNever<T>;
  }
  throw new Error("Not a number!");
}
```

Is this a good way to do it?